# NoMethodError　undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a error that

> NoMethodError in HomeController#index undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass .

```
@id = params[:id]
@email = [:email]
if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
  render :text =>   "sucsess"
else
  render :text =>   "fail"
```

Error message told me these codes were strange.It says `undefined method 'id'`,so is `@id` of if `@id == @user.id` seem method?(I think I define `@id` is variable)

What should I do to fix it?

**home_controller**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @id = params[:id]
    @email = [:email]
    if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
      render :text =>   "成功"
    else
      render :text =>   "失敗"
    end
  end

  def create
    userData = UserData.new(create_params)
    user = User.find(params[:id]).to_json

    # エラー処理
    unless  userData.save
      @error_message = [memo.errors.full_messages].compact
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"
  get 'home/index'
  post 'home/index'

  namespace :home, default: {format: :json} do
    resources :index, only: :create
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a value for `@user` that's why it says undefinded method `id`. You must have value for it like:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@user = User.first
```

On your code:

```
def index
  @user = User.first # defined User here like code on this line I added
  @id = params[:id]
  @email = [:email]
  if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
    render :text =>   "成功"
  else
    render :text =>   "失敗"
  end
end
```

You should make sure that you defined it. If you have `before_filter :your_method_define_user, only: [:index]`, make sure that `:your_method_define_user` has a value for `@user`.

As @Deepak Mahakale written above. I guess you are confused. Try the full code:

**UPDATED:**

Your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'home/index' # you must decide what to use post or get. But I use get here as default how index method is implemented in rails.
  root to: "home#index"
end
```

Your controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user, only: [:index]

  def index 
    @id = params[:id]
    @email = [:email]
    if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
      render :text =>   "成功"
    else
      render :text =>   "失敗"
    end
  end

  def create
    userData = UserData.new(create_params)
    user = User.find(params[:id]).to_json

    # エラー処理
    unless  userData.save
      @error_message = [memo.errors.full_messages].compact
    end
  end



  private

    def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) # You should specify this code what are your comparing to.
    end
end
```

Add you should pass the parameters in url if you use get request, like:

```
localhost:3000/home?id=<your_id>&email=<email_address>
```

and if post pass it on the fields provided in your form.

Comment: thx, ur comment.
I wrote my code like yours,but I got errors like
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#index
Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Comment: @Rose2017, additional, why are you using 2 request with the same method `home#index`? What is your goal with it?

Comment: I wanna make a server that app users can login & logout, but I am a beginner so I don't know why mu code are wrong.u told me that Im  using 2 request with the same method home#index,which parts are 2 requests?I thought my code have only if-else method.

Comment: @Rose2017, please check my answer I have updated it.

Comment: @Rose2017, is it worked? If it is, please accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> NoMethodError in HomeController#index undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass .

@user is `nil` in index action

You need to set the `@user` first in index action or in `before_filter`

**Solution 1**

```
def index
  @id = params[:id]
  @email = [:email]
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # or current_user whatever your logic is
  if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
    render :text =>   "成功"
  else
    render :text =>   "失敗"
  end
end
```

**Solution 2**

Add a `before_filter` for `index` action

```
before_filter :find_user, only: [:index]

private

def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # or current_user implement this according to your logic
end
```

Comment: Change  `@user = current_user` to `@user = find_user` so he can't will not confuse.

Comment: In the first solution I am not calling the private method but `current_user` helper which will give you current logged in user , Its from devise

Comment: I changed it to `User.find(id)`

Comment: So, what's the use of your before filter now in your answer? If you included `user = User.find(params[:id])` in the index?

Comment: It's second solution

Comment: @DeepakMahakale thx,ur comment. I wrote my codes like u wrote above,

Comment: It is much better now.

Comment: class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user

private

def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # or current_user implement this according to your logic
end

Comment: what are exacly comparing? params[:id] with logged in user or some specific user?

Comment: @Rose2017, you should add the private method in your code, let me update my answer below and try to use it.

Comment: @Rose2017, check my answer below. Check the full code I have written

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I wrote my code like u wrote, but I got a error like
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#index
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
So,what should I do ?Why does ur code work?

Comment: That means you don't have the record with `id = whatever value you are passing`

Comment: Make sure you are passing the id of available record